# Is there an advantage in using Visual Studio 2005(c++) when programing on Windows CE to control latency issues?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, latency

Is there an advantage in using Visual Studio 2005(c++) when programing on Windows CE (32bit) to control latency issues or any other?  I have heard 2008 and 2010 limit what you can and can't do.

thx

Answer (score 1):

You "heard" incorrectly.  Studio 2008 let's you compile native apps for CE no differently than 2005 did (though I think the '08 compiler is probably a better one, and more standards-compliant).

Studio 2010 "limits" you in that you can't do any CE device development with it at all because Microsoft didn't include device support or any of the device compilers (Windows Phone excepted).